# Get window handle from window class name

Tags: c#, winapi, window-handles, findwindow

I'm trying to get a window handle on a child window in my process and the only information I have is the window class name. Are there any win32 functions I can use for that? I'm doing this from C#.

A bit more detail: This is a Visual Studio plugin, written in C#. So my process is visual studio, which has lots of windows. One of them has a window class "VsTipWindow". I don't know the immediate parent window of that window, all I have is the class name. Is there any way for me to get the window handle from just that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off it should be noted that there is not a 1 to 1 relationship between windows and window classes, more than one window could use the same class.

I guess your only option is to call EnumChildWindows recursivly starting with the top level Visual Studio window (Or some other window higher in the window hierarchy if you know one that is a grandparent of the VsTipWindow window) In the callback function from EnumChildWindows you would call GetClassName and compare the string with VsTipWindow until you find the window.

Since you talked about unknown parent I'm assuming that you are after a child window, but if this window is a top level window, you need to use EnumWindows (And you should probably use GetWindowThreadProcessId to make sure you get the correct process also after you find a window with that classname)

(I'm sure .NET has functions that do the same thing as the native api, or you'd have to PInvoke)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Although to be clear "EnumChildWindows recursivly", you actually just call it once with the top level window handle, the EnumChildWindows function itself does the recursion already.

Answer (score 3):

[FindWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.findwindow) is the Win32 call you want for this (or [FindWindowEx](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindowEx.html) if there's more than one window with that particular class name, and FindWindow isn't returning the one you're looking for).

Comment: I just noticed the `findwindow` tag of your question - good guess. :)

Comment: FindWindow only finds top level windows, FindWindowEx is what you really mean, BUT it is safer to call the Enum function so you don't miss any windows

Comment: @Anders: already added the FindWindowEx link. In most cases like this, FindWindow returns the window you want. The safest approach of all is to not muck around with windows class names in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

just additional information..
maybe it's useful to know that you can get the handle of a window from a point
WindowFromPoint
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633558(VS.85).aspx

Comment: WindowFromPoint does not apply here, unless you are suggesting that the user must point the cursor on this window at a specific time or event!

Comment: @Anders, VsTipWindow is a kind of a ToolTipWindow. Tooltipwindows have the nature to be visible when the mouse is over another window and disappear when the mouse leaves the window. but nevertheless WindowFromPoint has nothing to do with the mouse point itself. it delivers a window handle of every arbitrary point. If it does apply here or not is not the question, please read my first 3 words. I just want to give another idea just in case Einars first idea will not work. we even do not know what he is about to do

Answer (score 0):

A Win32 window class is the generic implementation of a control, the handle of the windows is the instance of the control. So you will have multiple window handles with the same window class (e.g.: EDIT). Strictly speaking, a window class is the pointer to the window procedure.

Frameworks like .net (and even MFC) tend to share few window class for all the windows controls, and then they will dispatch to the appropriate controls (i.e. they have a single generic window procedure). This is the same also for big applications like Visual Studio or Office.

So this renders very difficult to detect a specific windows just through its window class. However, you can enumerate all the windows that have a specific windows class with `FindWindow`, you will get also the window text that may help you. Using `GetWindowThreadProcessId` you can detect if the window is belonging to Visual Studio.

Comment: Ok. But in this particular case I know there to be only one active window at a time with that particular window class so that is not a problem. I  probably should have stated that in the question :)