# How can C# to get the program name list in ToolbarWindow32/notification bar?

Tags: c#, windows, toolbar, handle, notification-bar

I'm using a note program,it runs good most of the time,but sometimes it can't display in the Windows Notification bar(I'm not sure if this is the correct name), so i can't click the icon to maximum the program,if I tried to restart the program,it even can't display in the notification bar by ten times attempts.

So I want to write a tiny `C# program`,Because I found that a lot of grammar is similar to java...(Let's call the program `< tinyStarter >`) I want it to do one simple job:
using windows command line to call a target program,after a short while(5 seconds maybe),`< tinyStarter >` will check if the program name list is in the right-down-corner of windows desktop (is it called Notification Bar?),if not,recalling the program until it displays.

I used `spy++` to locate the target program's area,then it shows:

```
Handle:000100DE;
Caption:Notification area for user upgrade
Class:ToolbarWindow32
```

So the question is ,is there any chance to using C# to get program name list in `ToolbarWindow32` ,or at least the count of them?

I actually did some efforts to solve another problem ,
see the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65624435/how-can-c-sharp-webbrowser-reduce-the-memory-occupying-how-to-solve-webbrowsers),
so the question in this thread was not done much searching and trying yet,I ask the question here just because I hope this question can be soveld easily by some experts.When I was doing some efforts on the other problem,the note program can't be opened normally can be very annoyed after all.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to defeat windows’ “choose which icons to show near the clock” facility/always show your program’s icon?

Comment: It's called the system tray

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943931/get-window-handle-from-window-class-name

Comment: I am afraid not. “choose which icons to show near the clock” is a setup of Windows ,what I am asking for is C# or Windows API code for looking up / finding / specifing a icon program name in system tray ...(correct me if I was wrong)

Comment: Thanks for GazTheDestroyer,system tray,I got it .

Comment: Actually I had done some searching on internet a few days ago about this issue,the link GazTheDestroyer shared mentioned FindWindow and FindWindowEx API which I had already tried to using them in some ways ,but I haven't find a correct method to find the NAME of a icon program yet.Maybe I should paste some codes in this or maybe another thread later.I was struggling with WebBrowser recently,after that I will try these two APIs again .Thank you again.